# Why on-change event working once in drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

```
registry.byId("ddlDistrict").on("change", function () {
    alert(dom.byId("ddlDistrict").value);
    if (findParams.searchText = dom.byId("ddlDistrict").value) {

         {
             findParams.searchFields = ["districtname"];
             findTask.execute(findParams, showResults);
         }

    }
});
```

Can anybody help me to make this code work for dependent drop-down.
I have cascading drop-down. heen i make autopostback false the above function working for every event but dependent drop-down is not working.

Comment: Can you include the code for the dependent drop down?

Comment: Might it be, that you have two "{" too much after you opend the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

In your if code  you are making an assignement not a comparaison :

so add another equal "=" to value comparison 
or tow other equal for type and value comparison

```
if (findParams.searchText === dom.byId("ddlDistrict").value) {
...
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Another note @Venkatesh : the onchange event return a value of your dijit in the callback function ,  no need to call `registry.byId("ddlDistrict").value` ,  

`registry.byId("ddlDistrict").on("change", function (value) {
alert("value of dijit = "+value);
....
}`